# how to work with UIDatePicker in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate, uidatepicker

I built a UI that has 3 `UIDatePicker`

The first `UIDatePicker` named `date` will be for `Date` only (Mode `.Date`)

Other `UIDatePicker`s names `time_from` and `time_to` will be for `Time` (From time, To time) (Mode `.Time`)

Then I add a `Button`,
When I click the button I need to get two variables:
`From_DateTime` and `To_DateTime`

(I need the Date from `date` UI and the time from `time_from`, `time_to`
[image]

[image]

I try a lot but without the desired result:

```
let date = date.calendar
    let date_components = date.components(.Calendar, fromDate: date.date)

    let date_from_components = dateFrom.calendar.components(.Calendar, fromDate: dateFrom.date)
    let date_to_components = dateTo.calendar.components(.Calendar, fromDate: dateTo.date)


    let n = date.calendar.dateBySettingHour(date_from_components.hour, minute: date_from_components.minute, second: 5, ofDate: dateFrom.date, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
```

This is an example of fails trying.

I need a simple way to get `From_DateTime` and `To_DateTime`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "US")
timeFormatter.dateFormat = " HH:mm"

let date_from = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date.date) + timeFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFrom.date)
let date_to = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date.date) + timeFormatter.stringFromDate(dateTo.date)
```

I am sure there must be another simple way.